# Converting text to binary with javascript

Tags: javascript, function, text, binary

Okay so I have seen a couple solutions to this problem however none of them are working for me. How do I convert text to binary with javascript?

```js
function asciiConverter() {
  var output = '';
  var phrase =  document.getElementById('phrase').value;  
    phrase = phrase.split('');
    for (var i =0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
      output += 0 + phrase[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + " ";
    } document.getElementById('ascii').innerHTML = output; 
}
```

```html
<div id="converter">
      <h2>Type a phrase to be converted to binary via Ascii:</h2>
      <h3>Your phrase</h3>
      <textarea name="phrase" id="phrase" cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Write your text here. . ." onkeyup="asciiConverter()"></textarea>
      <h3>Your phrase in Binary</h3>
      <input id="asciiButton" type="button" value="Convert!" onclick="asciiConverter()"/>
      <div id="ascii" ></div>
```

This works unless there are spaces or any special characters. I would like it to work with spaces and special characters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty guys I figured it out! this way it will make sure it will always have the 00's it leaves off at the beginning!

```js
function asciiConverter() {
  var code;
  var output = '';
  var phrase =  document.getElementById('phrase').value;  
    phrase = phrase.split('');
    for (var i =0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
      code = phrase[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2);
      if (code.length !== 8) {
        code = '0' + code;
        if (code.length !== 8) {
          code = '0' + code;
        }
```